# Store data in a table without using a CSV list in a column

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have the following table:

```
+-----------+--------------+
|categoryID | categoryName |
+-----------+--------------+
| 0         | Bills        |
| 1         | Gas          |
| 2         | Coffee       |
| 3         | Restaurants  |
+-----------+--------------+
```

All my users have access to this table however, the users would like to be able to sort the table how they see fit (and not necessarily alphabetically or sequentially) and have their sort order preference saved.  They would also like to hide categories that they don't use.

For example:

User 1 wants their table to look like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+
|categoryID | categoryName |
+-----------+--------------+
| 3         | Restaurants  |
| 0         | Bills        |
| 1         | Gas          |
+-----------+--------------+
```

User 2 wants their table to look like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+
|categoryID | categoryName |
+-----------+--------------+
| 0         | Bills        |
| 1         | Gas          |
| 2         | Coffee       |
+-----------+--------------+
```

User 3 wants their table to look like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+
|categoryID | categoryName |
+-----------+--------------+
| 3         | Restaurants  |
| 1         | Gas          |
| 0         | Bills        |
| 2         | Coffee       |
+-----------+--------------+
```

The only way I can think of to make this work is to make a table such as this one:

```
+-------+---------+
|userID | sort    |
+-------+---------+
| 1     | 3,0,1   |
| 2     | 0,1,2   |
| 3     | 3,1,0,2 |
+-------+---------+
```

**Question:** I've been told storing a CSV list in a column is not a good practice, but I have no idea how else to accomplish this.  How can I accomplish what I want without storing a CSV list in a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store delimited values in your database because you won't be able to normally maintain and query your data.

Instead create many-to-many table (let's call it user_categories) which may look like this

```
CREATE TABLE user_categories
(
  `userid` int, 
  `categoryid` int, 
  `sort_order` int,
  primary key (userid, categoryid),
  foreign key (userid) references users (userid),
  foreign key (categoryid) references categories (categoryid)  
);
```

Sample content for three users mentioned in your question will look like

```
| USERID | CATEGORYID | SORT_ORDER |
|--------|------------|------------|
|      1 |          3 |          1 |
|      1 |          0 |          2 |
|      1 |          1 |          3 |
|      2 |          0 |          1 |
|      2 |          1 |          2 |
|      2 |          2 |          3 |
|      3 |          3 |          1 |
|      3 |          1 |          2 |
|      3 |          0 |          3 |
|      3 |          2 |          4 |
```

Then you can do

```
SELECT c.categoryid, c.categoryname
  FROM user_categories uc JOIN categories c
    ON uc.categoryid = c.categoryid
 WHERE userid = 1
 ORDER BY uc.sort_order
```

Sample output:

```
| CATEGORYID | CATEGORYNAME |
|------------|--------------|
|          3 |  Restaurants |
|          0 |        Bills |
|          1 |          Gas |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a993e5/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

The other way you can accomplish this is to have sort table consisting of user_id, category_id,order 
The order will store the order from 1 the highest category 2 category after that and so on.

```
user_id | category_id | order
1       | 2           | 1
1       | 3           | 2
```